# override library method using Scala Implicit

Tags: scala, implicit

I'm using a library which has a class `Product` like

```
class Product {
   def toString() = "Whatever"  
}
```

I want to override this `toString` method. So there are two solutions.

> 1 - Copy the contents of that class and make same new class in you own project and do whatever with that method now.
>   2 - Use `Scala Impilicit`

1st approach is very pathetic. So I tried the 2nd one, but facing the issue. I'm successful in adding the new method in that class but unable to override the existing one. Let me explain it with example:

```
class NewProduct(val p: Product) {
   override def toString() = "an-other whatever"
}
implicit def customToString(p: Product) = new NewProduct(p)
```

Now if i prints in this way `println((new Product()).toString)` It prints     `whatever` but I was expecting `an-other whatever`
 It seems that it is not overriding that method, because if I add new Method then it works as expected as

```
class NewProduct(val p: Product) {
   def NewtoString() = "an-other whatever"
}
implicit def customToString(p: Product) = new NewProduct(p)
```

Now if i prints in this way `println((new Product()).NewtoString)` It prints `an-other whatever` its mean new Method `NewtoString` is added to that class.

What I'm missing ?
Is it possible to override methods using impicit in Scala ??

Answer (score 7):

Implicits are used if scala compiler cannot find method without it, so you can`t override methods with implicits. 
Use inheritance for this tasks.

```
class NewProduct extends Product {
    override def toString() = "an-other whatever"
}
```

Comment: so what can I do in this situation ? I've a Jar containing that class, now what can i do to override that method ?

Comment: inheritance is the key word.

Comment: the recommended way is inheritance. but there are situations when you can not simply inherit (class is final or the api has a very deep structure). then the only options you have is either replacing that class in the jar or byte code manipulation - both options are ugly ..