# elegant global override for toString in scala

Tags: scala

I have found myself frequently hard-pinning the console output of objects, into test code, as the expected output of unit tests. This makes me have to manually quote any string literals though, as Scala will print them without quotes to the console. Whereas other than that, a printed object is a perfect scala expression, strings aside.

With RTL languages this is a big annoyance as eclipse sucks at letting you navigate within RTL text when numbers are involved in the same text.

To the point then ― how can I elegantly override `toString` behavior in scala (to include quotes around strings) rather than override each and every class of interest that has strings in it? what would be the most elegant way?

Comment: What do you mean with "hard-pinning console output of objects", and why are you using console output in unit tests?

Comment: E.g. module is perfect. You take outputs and place them as expected outputs for next test runs, to make it future proof. Not always, but sometimes this fits a scenario.

Comment: I still don't really understand what it means to "take outputs". Can you show a code example of what you're doing now?

Comment: can you print in your question some output that you receive and some that you want to receive. actually you can use implicit object with toString for noncase classes. but overriding method for existing class is not possible on the JVM — in either Java or Scala

Comment: You can not use implicits: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30975609/651140

Comment: @AndrzejJozwik I think the link you pasted says the reverse :(

Comment: @matanster - the comment: `Implicits are used if scala compiler cannot find method without it, so you cant override methods with implicits`. Example is how to make it by inheritance. If you use logger (slf4j) - you can override handler, see for example [SLF4JBridgeHandler](http://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/bridge/SLF4JBridgeHandler.html)