# override equals method for string class in a package in a scala project

Tags: scala, overriding, implicit

So the problem statement is as it says. I want to override the behaviour of equals in string class in a specific package.

I've looked around and mostly it seems there's no way to do this.

The closest i got to defining a method on an existing class was this -

```scala
implicit class StringImprovements(s: String) {
  def increment = s.map(c => (c + 1).toChar)
}
```

and then use it like this -

```scala
"HAL".increment
```

Which is quite honestly amazing. But then i tried overriding equals using the same approach, it doesn't work.
I looked around and found this question from 2015 - [override library method using Scala Implicit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30975410/override-library-method-using-scala-implicit)

Citing a line from above mentioned question -

> Implicits are used if scala compiler cannot find method without it, so you can`t override methods with implicits

But given that scala releases are very frequent and things keep changing all the time, I was wondering whether it's possible to do so now, by this means or any other.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Even if it was possible, you could only override String#equals for your own code (because it has to make use of your implicit). Anything else that is already compiled against the "normal" String won't be affected and the result will be extremely confusing, especially with such a core method.

Comment: @Thilo It seems i shouldn't have used the word "everywhere in my project". It is misleading, sorry for the confusion, I've edited it to "specific packages". So basically "all of my code"

Comment: Well, you cannot do this. You have to either choose a different method name or box the String into your own type `MySpecialString` on which you can then define `equals` (and `hashCode`) to your liking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible. And if it were, I would expect a lot of library code to break because it expected normal behavior from `String#equals`!

Comment: I'm not talking about behaviour of String equals changing everywhere, only in the scope of packages i specify, where i have to import the particular implicit class specifically. So library code will never break. Right? Please correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: It seems i shouldn't have used the word "everywhere in my project". It is misleading, sorry for the confusion, I've edited it to "specific packages". So basically "all of my code"

Comment: This would still be very weird. When you use strings as map keys or set members, do you expect it to use your equality or the standard one? What if the map is returned from a library method? As Thilo's comment says, it makes more sense to define your separate type (and possibly add implicit conversions to and/or from `String`) instead.